# How to make a proper "pure" for an Applicative instance?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I've found out that there are at least 2 realizations of `pure` for this Applicative instance, that follow all the laws (Identity, Homomorphism, Interchange, Composition). Is one of them still wrong?

```
data List a = 
    Nil 
  | Cons a (List a) 
  deriving (Eq, Show) 

newtype ZipList' a = 
  ZipList' (List a) 
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Applicative ZipList' where 
  ZipList' fss <*> ZipList' xss = ZipList' $ applicate fss xss
    where applicate (Cons f fs) (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (applicate fs xs)
          applicate Nil         _           = Nil
          applicate _           Nil         = Nil
```

```
pure x = ZipList' (Cons x Nil)
```

or

```
pure a = ZipList' as
  where as = Cons a as
```

Comment: Yes, the first one is wrong. Since `pure id <*> Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)` will *not* yield `Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)`.

Comment: Your first one is the `pure` implementation for the `List` instance, not `ZipList`. It's possible that the same type could have two valid instances for a typeclass.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first `pure`, the *identity* law does *not* hold. Indeed, this law says that:

```
pure id <*> v = v
```

This thus means that:

```
ZipList' (Cons id Nil) <*> v = v
```

for all *`v`*s. But that does not hold. Say that `v = ZipList' (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))`, so basically a list `[1,2]`. Then one expects that:

```
ZipList' (Cons id Nil) <*> ZipList' (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)) = ZipList' (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))
```

If we however evaluate your implementation for `Applicative`, we see that:

```
ZipList' (Cons id Nil) <*> ZipList' (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))
    = ZipList' (applicate (Cons id Nil) (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)))
    = ZipList' (Cons (id 1) (applicate Nil (Cons 2 Nil)))
    = ZipList' (Cons 1 Nil)
```

But this is not what we expect for the identity law, since here we obtain a `ZipList'` that basically is `[1]`, whereas it should be `[1,2]`.

Comment: Is there only one `pure` implementation for any `Applicative` instances?

Comment: @kirillfedorov, yes, there is. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Each `<*>` can support at most one valid `pure`. Suppose `pure1` and `pure2` are both lawful. Then for any `x`,

```
pure2 x
= -- Identity for pure1
pure1 id <*> pure2 x
= -- Interchange for pure2
pure2 ($x) <*> pure1 id
= -- Functor/Applicative for pure2
fmap ($x) (pure1 id)
= -- Functor/Applicative for pure1
pure1 ($x) <*> pure1 id
= -- Homomorphism for pure1
pure1 x
```